# Creating Images - JavaME

Tags: java, java-me

I am having some issue trying to create image using createImage() using j2me.  The prog will just hang. I am able to get input from file but I can't createImage. Does anyone have any idea?

```
    if (filenames.exists()) {  
    InputStream input = filenames.openInputStream();  
    try { Logger.logEventInfo("READING1: " + imageName);
    Image image = Image.createImage(input); //Having problem here...
```

Comment: You can try using one of the other Image.createImage methods to see if it's the image data that's causing the problem. Just read from the InputStream into a byte array and call `createImage(byte[] imageData, int imageOffset, int imageLength)`

Comment: Thanks! This works! Any idea why it doesn't work with createImage(input)?

Answer (score 0):

Try using createImage(String name) version of the method if you are just trying to load the data from an image file. Make sure the image is a PNG, and in the resource (res) folder.  The String should be in the format "/filename.png" -- note the leading slash.

Comment: i'm not sure but shouldn't it be `/res/filename.png`, assuming the final jar has the `res` dir?

Comment: I'm using the JavaME SDK 3.0 and once you have a folder added as a resource for the project, you do not need to specify folder name -- just the filename. With the older tool (the WTK -- Wireless ToolKit), it was the same way, except that you couldn't choose your resource folder... it was always "res".